# You probably don't have the courage to solve this. (THE LIST: PART 1)

Tags: knowledge, cipher, story

*ONE DAY, YOU WERE SCROLLING ON YOUR PHONE WHEN, YOUR MOM TEXTED YOU. READ THE STRING OF TEXTS:*

---

***MOM:*** Hi honey! On the counter, I have put a list for you to do. But, keep in mind that one step is missing. This list might not be what you think, but, remember to trust your guts and I have faith that you'll figure it out in the end.

***YOU:*** What does that even mean?

***MOM:*** You'll soon know.

***YOU:*** Okay? But, why don't you just keep the step in there so I don't have to figure it out.

***YOU:*** Mom?

***YOU:*** Are you there?

*ALL OF A SUDDEN, A LOUD BANGING SOUND COMES FROM THE KITCHEN. "MOM! IS THAT YOU?!" BUT, WHEN YOU GET TO THE KITCHEN ALL YOU SEE IS A PAPER NEATLY FOLDED ON THE COUNTER LABELED, 'LIST'. YOU UNFOLD THE PAPER AND COMPLETE THE LIST STARTING WITH NUMBER ONE.*

---

**LIST:**

1. ANQM HM SGD T.R. (16)
2. YPC WMS QSPC RFGQ GQ Y EMMB GBCY? (12)
3. X JLKPQBO. (7)
4. BNEHHU. (4)
5. VNNZHWGDIB OCZ WPIF. (12)

> This one was described weirdly, so, I changed it.

6. IB, NBUN GUEYM MYHMY! (7)
7. ZXM KXOXGZX HG ABF. (10)
8. ESMJG ESCWK EW KWDX-UGFKUAGMK. (18)

> ESMJG isn't meant to be a person. This one doesn't make that much sense, but, it's pretty simple.

9. R XIZVMRETV. (9)
10. WEET BEEAI CUQD DEJXYDW. (16)
11. P NDJCV STHXGT. (12)

---

**WHAT DO THE STEPS MEAN? AND WHAT IS THE MISSING ONE?**

> There should be 12 steps, but, one's missing.

Comment: Just so you know... the title isn't meant to be mean or to draw people in. I hope it makes sense when you solve it!

Comment: Okay, @PDT how do you start a chat with someone? You can tell me what you think it is on there and help me make things more clear.

Comment: Or, you can start a chat with me.

Comment: Okay! I hope you're right!

Comment: Just added some hints!

Comment: The one you said was described weirdly and changed was the only one I understood. Besides 7.

Comment: Yeah.. sorry, I'm very new to this stuff. It's hard to give clues without giving it away :D

Comment: And.. how'd you get 7?

Comment: rot13(flabalzf nxn hfvat n gurfnhehf)

Comment: rot13(Vg'f abg nyy whfg flabalzf. Fbzr ner ernyyl pybfr gb flabalzf gubhtu.)

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer:

> If you *encode* (not decode) the lines using the caeser cipher with the key being the corresponding number (e.g. 1st task: key = 1, 2nd task: key = 2, etc.) then you get:
>  ANQM HM SGD T.R. -> BORN IN THE U.S.
>  YPC WMS QSPC RFGQ GQ Y EMMB GBCY? -> ARE YOU SURE THIS IS A GOOD IDEA?
>  X JLKPQBO. -> A MONSTER.
>  BNEHHU. -> FRILLY.
>  WPDGYDIB V KGVXZ AJM TJPM AGJRZMN. -> BUILDING A PLACE FOR YOUR FLOWERS.
>  IB, NBUN GUEYM MYHMY! -> OH, THAT MAKES SENSE!
>  ZXM KXOXGZX HG ABF. -> GET REVENGE ON HIM.
>  ESMJG ESCWK EW KWDX-UGFKUAGMK. -> MAURO MAKES ME SELF-CONSCIOUS.
>  R XIZVMRETV. -> A GRIEVANCE.
>  WEET BEEAI CUQD DEJXYDW. -> GOOD LOOKS MEAN NOTHING.
>  P NDJCV STHXGT. -> A YOUNG DESIRE.

Comment: Or you could decode with rot(number of task).That's how intended it to happen.

Comment: But, yes you're getting closer.

Comment: Technically, the "rot" in "rot13" implies the method is symmetrical. Encoding and decoding rot13 are the same operation, which is its own inverse. Likewise for rot47 and rot8000. But when you use shifts other than 13 for a Caesar cipher and call it "rot", you start to get into disagreements about whether you're encrypting or decrypting and whether "encrypt with a shift of 1" and "decrypt with a shift of 25" are distinct operations.